# Java - Compare Strings that may contain numbers, without the number of digits interfering

Tags: java, string, numbers, string-comparison

I have an issue with comparing Strings that sometimes contain numbers.

Let's say I have two Strings; *s1 = "Chapter 9"* and *s2 = "Chapter 10"*

Any human would say that, if these are to be sorted, *s1* would end up earlier than *s2* and that also happens in Windows folders. However, in Java it just checks one *char* at a time until one is greater/lesser than the other, which leads to it putting *s2* earlier than *s1* due to it having a '1' where *s1* has a '9'

Is there a way of managing this that does not involve a lot of code and/or processing?

Comment: That kind of depends on what you mean by "a lot of code and/or processing". Does getting the number using a regular expression count as "a lot of processing"?

Comment: You can implement your own Comparator, to sort these things like you wish.

Comment: sort would work if you can make *"Chapter 9"* into *"Chapter 09"* (unless you have chapter 100 and then you need to make it into *"Chapter 009"* :)